# Collecting Visual Studio Intellisense results from command line

Tags: json, visual-studio, validation, schema, intellisense

When you open json files that have a "$schema" property in Visual Studio 2017, intellisense will add messages to the Error List window describing which lines in the file do not match the schema (e.g. missing required property, wrong data type, doesn't match pattern, etc.). This only happens if the file is currently open.

I would like these results to show up when I build (even if the json files are not open). I don't want to make an extension to do it, but I do currently run a custom executable during the build. I know how to format the output of the executable so that errors and warnings generated by that tool show up in the Error List window.

Basically, I am wondering if I can use that to somehow force the intellisense results specifically from the json files to appear in the Error List window. I would like to have the ability to promote some of the messages to errors and some to warnings, so I don't just want to hack it in by forcing the json files to open during the build. (Can I somehow use MsBuild to get intellisense results from json files?)

If there is no way to collect the results of intellisense in an external tool, then I will most likely use a completely separate json validation library instead. I just wanted to save the effort since it is built into Visual Studio. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that NJsonSchema (https://github.com/RSuter/NJsonSchema) is so easy to use. If anyone has ideas about intellisense, that may still be useful, though.

Comment: Thank you for your sharing, please mark it as answer when you have free time, it is just a reminder :)